# Converting running pace

Tags: java, calendar

I'm trying to convert a running pace that I get in the format of a String (say : "5:00" for a 5 min/mile).  (I am converting min/mile to min/km).

So here's what I'm doing :

```
String milePace = "05:00";
DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("mm:ss");
Date date = sdf.parse(milePace);

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(date);

long mileTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();
long kmPace = Math.round(mileTime * 0.623712);

cal.setTimeInMillis(kmPace);
```

This unfortunately makes sense to me, but does not work.

0.623712 would be the converting unit and does work (as long as I am concerned).

When I check the value of `mileTime` I get 18240000.  As far I can see, this is the issue as this value should be 240000 (which would be 4mins * 60 secs * 1000)

Is there an issue with the code or is there something from the cal function that would give me that extra 18000000 miliseconds?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getTimeInMillis()` returns the number of milliseconds since 1970 UTC. It will be affected by the time zone of your parser, and what date the parser decides to use for your input.

I would suggest that you use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) and parse the value as a `Period` instead.

Sample code:

```
import org.joda.time.*;
import org.joda.time.format.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text = "05:00";

        PeriodFormatter formatter = new PeriodFormatterBuilder()
            .minimumPrintedDigits(2)
            .appendMinutes()
            .appendSeparator(":")
            .appendSeconds()
            .toFormatter();

        Period milePeriod = formatter.parsePeriod(text);

        long mileMillis = milePeriod.toStandardDuration().getMillis();
        long kmMillis = Math.round(mileMillis * 0.623712);

        PeriodType minutesSeconds = PeriodType.time()
            .withMillisRemoved()
            .withHoursRemoved();

        Period kmPeriod = new Period(kmMillis, minutesSeconds);

        System.out.println(formatter.print(kmPeriod)); // Prints 03:07
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your 
`Calendar.getInstance();` change this to

`Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();`

`cal.set(<Calendar Constants);` [Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#set%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29)

`long miletime = cal.getTimeInMillis();`

Answer (score 0):

If you know that your time will stay between 0s and 59 mins inclusive, with a granularity of 1s, you could do it like this:

```
s = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat ("s");
m = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat ("m");
int secs = Integer.parseInt (s.format (sdf.parse ("05:00")));
int mins = Integer.parseInt (m.format (sdf.parse ("05:00")));
```

Adding hours might not be necessary - or do you measure something that slow?